# How do I change record labels in BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

What is the way to convert the following data from

```
[{
  "browsing_itemid": {
    "list": [{
      "element": "yyy"
    }]
  }
}, {
  "browsing_itemid": {
    "list": [{
      "element": "xxx"
    }]
  }
}]
```

to this format?

```
[{
    "browsing_itemid": {
      "bag": [{
        "array_element": "yyy"
      }]
    }
  }, {
    "browsing_itemid": {
      "bag": [{
        "array_element": "xxx"
      }]
    }
}]
```

Altering nested column names are not working using `ALTER TABLE`? Is Custom JS function, best way to do this?

Comment: Do you have the updated JSON (updated labels and data) prepared on your end?

Comment: I have the updated schema in another table, I am trying to insert list.element into bag.array_element.

Comment: Hi @katrocitus, Since the altering of the column’s name is in pre-ga, it is having limited support as you can check in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas#change_a_columns_name). As a workaround, you can try `Alter Table Rename Column` statement as mentioned in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#alter_table_rename_column_statement). Let me know if that helps.